# Actualizar foto en formulario php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, crud

En esta tabla se muestran todos los registros almacenados en mi BBDD:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
<td>ID de Empleado</td>
<td>Nombre</td>
<td>Apellidos</td>
<td>Email</td>
<td>Coste por Hora</td>
<td>Departamento</td>
<td>Foto</td>
<td colspan="2">Opciones</td>
  </tr>
@foreach ($empleado as $emp)
<tr>
  <td>{{$emp->idEmpleado}}</td>
  <td>{{$emp->nombre}}</td>
  <td>{{$emp->apellidos}}</td>
  <td>{{$emp->email}}</td>
  <td>{{$emp->costeHora}}</td>
  <td>{{$emp->departamento}}</td>
  <td><img src="{{ asset('images/'.$emp->foto) }}" height="40" width="30"></td>
  <td><a href="{{route('empleadoVista.edit', $emp->id)}}">Editar</a></td>
  <td><a href="{{route('empleado.delete', $emp->id)}}">Eliminar</a></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>
```

En el siguiente formulario los campos ya aparecen rellenos con los datos del registro seleccionado:

```
    <form method="post" action="/empleadoVista/{{$empleado->id}}">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ID de Empleado/a:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="idEmpleado" value="{{$empleado->idEmpleado}}"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Nombre:</td>
    <td>  <input type="text" name="nombre" value="{{$empleado->nombre}}">{{csrf_field()}}</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Apellidos:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="apellidos" value="{{$empleado->apellidos}}"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" value="{{$empleado->email}}"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Coste por hora:</td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="any" name="costeHora" value="{{$empleado->costeHora}}"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Departamento:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="departamento" value="{{$empleado->departamento}}"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Foto:</td>
    <td><input type="file" name="foto" value="{{$empleado->foto}}"></td>
  </tr>

<tr>
  <td><input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar"></td>
<td><input type="reset" name="limpiar" value="Limpiar"></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

El problema es que en el campo "foto" no aparece nada y si selecciono una foto distinta a la que hay, no la actualiza y deja la misma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que hace mi controlador en el método edit:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $empleado=Empleado::FindOrFail($id);
    return view ("empleadoVista.edit", compact("empleado"));
}
```

Y esto es lo que hace en el método update:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $empleado=Empleado::FindOrFail($id);
        $empleado->update($request->all());
        return redirect("empleadoVista/listarTodos");
    }
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Me temo que no puedes usar el input file para enseñar una foto de esa manera, tendra que ser una imagen

Comment: No quiero que aparezca la vista previa, tan solo quiero que donde pone "ningun archivo seleccionado", aparezca la ruta de mi foto (en mi BBDD está guardada como un varchar). He hecho la prueba cambiando type=file por type=text y he visto que la ruta la coge...

Comment: No se entiende muy bien. En el campo `foto` hay una imagen en sí o una ruta a una imagen. Si es una ruta, tienes que usar `src` para mostrarla.

Comment: En el campo foto está la ruta a la imagen. Selecciono la foto, la guarda en una carpeta del proyecto, y en la BBDD guarda tan solo la ruta. A ver si se entiende mejor ahora con las imágenes nuevas.

Comment: En el metodo update, no subes la nueva imagen al servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado amigos!!!! Había dos problemas:

El primero es que en la cabecera del formulario no había puesto:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

El segundo es que almacenaba la foto en el disco pero no sobreescribía la que ya existía en la BBDD, por lo que la foto seguía siendo la misma. El update correcto sería el siguiente:

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $empleado=Empleado::FindOrFail($id);
        if ($request->hasFile('foto')){
            $archivoFoto=$request->file('foto');
            $nombreFoto=time().$archivoFoto->getClientOriginalName(); 
            $archivoFoto->move(public_path().'/images/', $nombreFoto);

  // esta es la línea que faltaba. Llamo a la foto del modelo y le asigno la foto recogida por el formulario de actualizar.          
        $empleado->foto=$nombreFoto; 

          }
        $empleado->update($request->all());
        return redirect("empleadoVista/listarTodos");
    }
```

Gracias a todos por la ayuda!!!

Answer (score 0):

Si guardas una imagen con el mismo nombre en repetidas ocaciones "images.jpeg" el navegador te va guardar en caché la primer imagen que recibió. Para visualizar el cambio inmediatamente, debes deshabilitar la caché del navegador, o guardar la imagen con un nombre distinto cada vez.

Comment: He probado a borrar la caché, a guardar una imagen distinta y usando navegadores distintos. Todo sigue igual... Muchas gracias igualmente!!